# where to find the variable of a function in prototypal chain?

Tags: javascript

```
function a(){
   var name ="Euler Henrique";
   var age =32;
}

console.log(a);
```

if that was an instance of a it would be easier to visualise it with when you console.log(a) i ran through prototypal chain everywhere and could not find var name and var age, i need it for learining purpose.

Comment: Those variables do not get added to the prototype chain at all.

Answer (score 3):

`name` and `age` are local variables in a function scope.

If you want to access variables from `a` function, you'll need to add them to the function itself:

```js
function a() {}
// Note that 'name' is a read-only property of Function
// whose value is the name of the whole function
a._name = 'Matías'
a.age = 33

console.log(a._name, a.age)
```

In the other hand, if you want both properties to be part of an object created using `a` as constructor, you'll need to attach them to `this`:

```js
function a() {
  this.name = 'Matías'
  this.age = 33
}

const instance = new a()

console.log(instance)
```

Finally, you might want to implement the *module pattern* so you could be able to publish or leave certain variables inaccessible from an outer scope:

```js
function a() {
  var name = 'Matías'
  var age = 33

  return {
    age
  }
}

const moduleA = a()

// name isn't published
console.log(moduleA)
```

Comment: examples easily convey the answer.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar yup, given that StackOverflow has runnable JS snippet, it's a good approach to answer certain questions.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere.

`var` variables exist in the scope of the function they are declared within.

They aren't a property of any object, let alone a prototype object.

(`var` variables declared outside of any function when strict mode is not enabled are a special case).